# Spring Boot application is not executable

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I am migrating my old Spring setup to Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.

I'm failing to get an executable .jar, I followed countless examples but my jar fails to become an executable.

It's a multi-module setup so here is my parent pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <name>xyz</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <commons.version>3.5</commons.version>
    <guava.version>21.0</guava.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>mainApp</module>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    ..........
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- google guava  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

This is the pom of the mainApp, it is the module that has Application.java which holds main method.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mainApp</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.xyz.mainApp</groupId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>mainApp</name>

  <dependencies>
<!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency> 


<!-- xyz dependencies -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.module3</groupId>
        <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.module2</groupId>
        <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
   <finalName>xyz</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

**Things that work:**

So things work okay when I do *mvn clean install* in the folder of parent pom.xml and then run mvn *spring-boot:run* in the mainApp folder

**Things that fail:**

when I execute *java -jar mainApp/target/xyz.jar*  I get an error like:

```
no main manifest attribute, in mainApp/target/xyz.jar
```

if I attempt to run the *jar like ./mainApp/target/xyz.jar*, well I can't as the file is not an executable, my macOS Sierra terminal shows this for file permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 userXYZ  staff  37641156 Feb  1 13:14 xyz.jar
```

If I manually change the permissions to *-rwxr--r--* and attempt to run the file I get this gibberish:

```
/xyz.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
./xyz.jar: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./xyz.jar: line 2: ?iAJ META-INF?iAJMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFu??J?0??y?y??,??nW*???Jb3?F?LI?????qa?n?3???)Mp5&V????ñ^IQ?????ޱ?.#??`?$?{<??7?m6?j܀?W????'????γڎ9?>????RT?͡?V??

G??

3iR?G4???dә?A(̀?z?ϖV]ٷ??T??O>?^??0wy?u?^??S]?iG?2?"???i?$?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not how the plugin is configured, but where the plugin is configured.

I have wrapped my plugins with `<pluginManagement>`, which was causing all the problems, when i removed it all was resolved and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

update your build block in pom.xml with following, make sure you are using using Maven 3.2 (or better):

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

the main class entry is missing in the jar manifesto.

Please modify the boot maven plugin as below:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

      <configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Plugin [info](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: things changed a little, i got an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
 at com.xyz.mainApp.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more